# Restoring backup from DB2 9.7 to DB2 10.1

Tags: database, db2, upgrade, restore, db2-luw

I have installed DB2 version 10.1 on a new machine running Windows Server 2012, and tried to restore a database from a backup made using DB2 version 9.7

I got this error while attempting to restore the database

[image: Error]

What can I do to restore the database from this backup?

P.S. Generating DDL is not an option since I don't have access to a running version of the database, neither is restoring the backup to a DB2 9.7 instance since I don't have access to the installation source for DB2 9.7

Comment: Can you create a temp directory and try this ? restore database MFFDB from Q:\Share\Stating_Backup taken at 20160614130701 logtarget "C:\temp\db2logs" redirect

Comment: Make sure to create the temp directory and replace it on the command I posted above

Comment: Apparently you have an online backup image, which requires a rollforward operation, which is not possible during the database upgrade. You can try adding `WITHOUT ROLLING FORWARD` at the end of your `RESTORE` command, but that may not work if the image is inconsistent. Ultimately the only supported "upgrade via restore" path is to use an offline backup image.

Comment: @CristianMeneses I tried it and got the same outcome, and there was no log file created at the temp folder

Comment: @mustaccio I added 'WITHOUT ROLLING FOWARD'  to the end of the statement and still got the same outcome

Comment: As @mustaccio mentioned, most probable cause is that your backup is an ONLINE backup, which means that it was taken "on hot", and to restore it, you need also the transaction logs from the database. This means that you need either the transaction logs to perform the roll forward operation, or an OFFLINE backup (which needs the database to be stopped while the backup is in progress)

Comment: Do you know if this error will still be there if I somehow find a DB2 9.7 installation source and try to restore the database on DB2 9.7 instead?

Comment: @CristianMeneses Logs won't help when upgrading to a newer version; log record format often changes between versions, and the newer version cannot use older logs for the rollforward.

Comment: @AhmedAnwar You'll be able to restore the database to a 9.7 installation.  You can then complete the roll forward and then perform the upgrade to 10.1.

Answer (score 1):

It is documented as:

```
Offline full database backups as well as offline incremental 
database backups can be restored to a later database version, 
whereas online backups cannot.
```

Here is V10.1 manual page, extracted from:
**RESTORE DATABASE command**
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0001976.html

Later V11.5 manual same page has the same statement.  We need an **offline** backup in this case.

Hope this helps.